# Add Dictionary Keys and Values to Redis List

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, redis, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to add the current dictionary to a Redis list using a dictionary comprehension and then to print out the first (aka current) keys and values of that list. I say current because this is a process I will be continuing with a while loop to have the list building over time, but I have to always access the first keys/values.

I am sure I am totally butchering this, but this is what I have:

```
adict = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}

{rserver.rpush("list",value) for value in adict}

print(float(rserver.lindex("list",0)))
```

I need to get a list of both keys and values back.

Help would be MUCH appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should be calling `LRANGE` instead of `LINDEX`.

Comment: If I do print(rserver.lrange("buylist",0,-1)) I only get the keys back. I need to get both the keys and the values..

Comment: For the next time please post a reproducible code-example, with imports etc. also your insert statement(line 2) will not work, because you are pushing the keys instead of the values, when using `_ for i in adict`; what you want to use is `_ for value in adict.values()`

Comment: I only get the values doing {rserver.rpush("list",value) for value in adict.values()}. How would I get both keys:values

Comment: for any dictionary you can access the (ordered) list of `.keys()`, `.values()` and the list of (key,values) by `.items()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite positive on what your redis-list should contain (please include your expected result in the question), but assuming it should at the end of inserts look something like this `["a:1", "b:1", "c:1"]`, you can achieve this with

```
adict = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
for key,value in adict.items():
  rserver.rpush("list", ":".join([key, value]))

print(float(rserver.lindex("list",0))) #>>> "a:1"
```

(as you have not included what interface `rserver` exactly is, it is a bit hard to guess on its exact behavior)